# Upgrade from Alfresco 3.4 to 5.1 Community Edition

Tags: alfresco

I want to upgrage Alfresco from 3.4 to 5.1 community Edition on linux
What should I do exactly ? ?

Comment: Did you try [reading and following the Alfresco documentation on doing an upgrade](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/upgrade-process.html)? If yes, where did you get stuck? If not, why not? And what happens when you try?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you cannot upgrade directly to 5.1.
You will have to update to 4.x beforehand and as a next step upgrade from 4.x to 5.1.

This is described here in the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/upgrade-path.html).

Briefly you will have to do following:

- backup your database and alf_data folder
- install 4.x
- configure it to use your existing (3.4) database and alf_data folder (in alfresco-global.properties)
- start it and wait till all upgrades scripts will execute successfully
- install 5.1
- configure it to use your existing database and alf_data folder (in alfresco-global.properties)
- start it and wait till all upgrades scripts will execute successfully

Please note that 5.1 don't have an user interface in /alfresco (repo) webapp.
GUI was separated to /share webapp so all your customization should be rewritten/reconfigured to be used inside Share.

For more information on how to upgrade Alfresco please follow instructions from this official documentation page [Upgrading Alfresco on a single instance](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/upgrade-singleinstance.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have "default configuration"- I mean like there you dont have some custom things like certificates, etc.. 
You dont need to backup & restore complete "alf_data", but just alf_data ***contentStore*** & ***contentStore.deleted*** should be fine

Also one importatnt thing

> database backup must be made firts, earlier than "data" backup- because of indexes saved in DB
>   (if there will be indexed some files, which will dont be in data, alfresco will dont start, if there will be some files without indexes, it will index them)

Btw also what is recommended is to make reindex (on new Alfresco)- steps has dependencies on the Alfresco version *(eg. Alf 4 has solr1, alf 5.x has solr4 by default)*, but its usually something like [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/solr-reindex.html)